Man with painting that shows his evil/corruption, while he remains handsome
This movie is about a man who lets evil get the better of him.  He goes and does bad stuff. He cheats on hes wife with other women and he has a painting of him self and every time he does bad stuff that painting looks more evil! 
It's set in the 1800s I think but I forgot the name of this film but I really want to watch it again.

As the three posters below have mentioned, this is definitely a version of Dorian Gray. But there are lots of adaptions of the original book, so you'll need to provide more detail to really narrow it down. Year it was released (or at least when you watched it) would be most helpful.

As the other answer stated, this is a movie based on the famous Oscar Wilde work, The Picture of Dorian Gray.
There have been an absurd number of film adaptations of this story with the most popular and recent being the 2009 version starring Ben Barnes and Colin Firth.
Further still this character made a number of appearances in movies and TV like League of Extraordinary Gentlemen and the Penny Dreadful Series.

This movie is (a version of) The Picture of Dorian Gray..

The Picture of Dorian Gray is an 1891 philosophical novel by Irish writer and playwright Oscar Wilde.
..Dorian Gray is the subject of a full-length portrait in oil by Basil Hallward, an artist who is impressed and infatuated by Dorian's beauty; he believes that Dorian’s beauty is responsible for the new mode in his art as a painter. Through Basil, Dorian meets Lord Henry Wotton, and he soon is enthralled by the aristocrat's hedonistic worldview: that beauty and sensual fulfilment are the only things worth pursuing in life.
Understanding that his beauty will fade, Dorian expresses the desire to sell his soul, to ensure that the picture, rather than he, will age and fade. The wish is granted, and Dorian pursues a libertine life of varied and amoral experiences; all the while his portrait ages and records every soul-corrupting sin.[5]


True, it is likely based on the Dorian Gray story, but this doesn't answer the OPs question.

On these lines, perhaps you're thinking of the "The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen", though it "features" Dorian Gray rather than it being about him

The definitive version of the Movie was made in 1945: The Picture of Dorian Gray.
It was directed by Albert Lewin who commissioned the artist Ivan Albright to paint a lurid portrait of the corrupted Gray (in colour despite the movie being monochrome). The painting is still on show in the Art Institute Chicago. 
There have, as other answers have pointed out, been a lot of other adaptations of this story, just not many memorable ones or any where a key prop is still on display in a major art museum.
This might not be the one you remember, but to be more specific you will need to provide more details about the particular version you saw.
